# Pass T entity to EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, repository

I have an Event which fires off on my `ProductManager` and I want to handle it in my `LoggerRepository`.

Question: How can I call `Insert(T entity)` from this event handler and pass `entity` to it?

```
public class LoggerRepository<T> : ILoggerRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IProductsManager _productsManager;
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public LoggerRepository(IProductsManager productsManager)
    {
        _productsManager = productsManager;
        _productsManager.OnPricesUpdated += _productsManager_OnPricesUpdated;
    }
    public LoggerRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }
    private void _productsManager_OnPricesUpdated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        **//HOW CAN I CALL Insert(entity) here**
    }
    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: @bommelding That is the question. I want to figure out how to call the `Insert` method which requires the `entity` parameter?

Comment: @bommelding isn't that possible to create a variable of type T and pass it as the third argument?